# Prefetch 3 level hierarchy of objects

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following model structure. If i want to prefetch the objects of ModelC containing the objects of ModelB i do `ModelC.objects.prefetch_related('ModelB').`
But how can i fetch the objects of ModelA contained in ModelB as well. I trided something like     `ModelC.objects.prefetch_related('ModelB').prefetch_related('ModelA').` but does not work

```
class ModelA:

class ModelB:
      ModelA = models.ForeignKey(
            ModelA, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_constraint=False)

class modelC:
    ModelB = models.ManyToManyField('ModelB', blank=True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
ModelC.objects.prefetch_related('ModelB__ModelA')
```

Comment: This is explicitly noted in [the docs for prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related).